# is there an analytic solution to $n^2+kn-d=m^2$ m,n integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratics

For $k=24,d=-17;m=8,n=3$, completing the square gives $(12+n)^2=m^2+161$ Where $161$ just happens to be the product of two primes $(q=7,p=23)$, so for large $k,m,n$ factoring may be very slow.

Alternatively, a sequence $17..29$ sums to $161$ and has $q=7$ terms, and the first is $2m+1$ and the last is $2q+2m-1$ (always(?)). Also $161 = q(q+2m)$. Obviously(?) $pq=161$ represents a hyperbola. I thought maybe there is a way to transform the equation to an ellipse or circle to make it more manageable, but it appears not so.

If factoring cannot be avoided, what method is most useful for $t>>161$, but $<=256=$digits.

Comment: What is fixed here and what is not? Also, what is $t?$

Comment: Oh, i missed this. Gerry and Marty have adequately answered my question. t was "for all cases > the example".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it the problem is, given (sizable) $k$ and $d$, find $m$ and $n$ such that the equation in the title holds. As you have seen in your example, this will come down to expressing some number as a difference of two squares. But doing this is just as hard as factoring, so in general you will not find a solution unless you can factor the numbers that arise.

Comment: Thanks, i was thinking it can't be avoided; are either of the forms <difference of squares>, <y=q(q+2m)> suitable for some method such as Pollard-Rho, or is there something better?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: There are methods of factorisation such as quadratic residue, and methods developed by Pollard using GCD/congruence. My question is, is there something similar for solving <difference of squares, eg (n+k/2)^2-m^2=161> or the other formulation eg 161=q(q+2m)?

Comment: Given $N$, the method for solving $x^2-y^2=N$, and the method for solving $x(x+2y)=N$, is to factor $N$.

Comment: Thanks that fully answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

If $n^2 + kn = m^2 + d$, 
$4n^2 + 4kn = 4m^2 + 4d$
or 
$4n^2 + 4kn + k^2= 4m^2 + 4d+k^2$
or
$(2n+k)^2 = 4m^2 + 4d+k^2$
or
$(2n+k)^2 - 4m^2 = 4d+k^2$
or
$(2n+k-2m)(2n+k+2m) = 4d+k^2$.

By looking at all the factorizations
of $4d+k^2$,
all possible values of
$n$ and $m$ can be determined.

More explicitly,
for each factorization
$4d+k^2 = a\cdot  b$
with $a \le b$,
try to solve
$a = 2n+k-2m$ and $b = 2n+k+2m$.

The algebra is easy:
$b-a = 4m$
and
$b+a = 4n+2k$,
so $m = (b-a)/4$
and
$n = (b+a-2k)/4$.

To have a solution in integers,
$b-a$ and $b+a+2k$ must both be divisible by 4,
so $k$ must be divisible by 2.

You can look into the factorization possibilities
more deeply,
but this should be enough
to write an algorithm
for any given $k$ and $d$.

Comment: yes, k is always divisible by 2. What your formulation does is also to represent the solution as 4p*4q, which correponds to factorization or the difference of squares. Thanks to you also.